# Query for getting previous date in oracle in specific scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below data in a table **A** which I need to insert into table **B** along with one computed column.

TABLE A:

```
Account_No |  Balance   |  As_on_date  
1001       |-100        |  1-Jan-2013  
1001       |-150        |  2-Jan-2013  
1001       | 200        |  3-Jan-2013  
1001       |-250        |  4-Jan-2013  
1001       |-300        |  5-Jan-2013  
1001       |-310        |  6-Jan-2013
```

Table B:

In table B, there should be no of days to be shown when balance is negative and
the date one which it has gone into negative.

So, for 6-Jan-2013, this table should show below data:

```
Account_No |  Balance   |  As_on_date   | Days_passed | Start_date   
1001       |    -310    |    6-Jan-2013 |    3        |     4-Jan-2013
```

Here, no of days should be the days when the balance has gone negative in recent time and
not from the old entry.

I need to write a SQL query to get the no of days passed and the start date from when the 
balance has gone negative.

I tried to formulate a query using `Lag` analytical function, but I am not succeeding.

How should I check the first instance of negative balance by traversing back using `LAG` function?

Even the `first_value` function was given a try but not getting how to partition in it based on negative value.

Any help or direction on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to achive this using analytical functions.

```
INSERT INTO tableb
   WITH tablea_grouped1
        AS (SELECT account_no,
                   balance,
                   as_on_date,
                   SUM (CASE WHEN balance >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                      OVER (PARTITION BY account_no ORDER BY as_on_date)
                      grp
              FROM tablea),
        tablea_grouped2
        AS (SELECT account_no,
                   balance,
                   as_on_date,
                   grp,
                   LAST_VALUE (
                      balance)
                   OVER (
                      PARTITION BY account_no, grp
                      ORDER BY as_on_date
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                           AND     UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
                      closing_balance
              FROM tablea_grouped1
             WHERE balance < 0 
               AND grp != 0 --keep this, if starting negative balance is to be ignored
           )
     SELECT account_no,
            closing_balance,
            MAX (as_on_date),
            MAX (as_on_date) - MIN (as_on_date) + 1,
            MIN (as_on_date)
       FROM tablea_grouped2
   GROUP BY account_no, grp, closing_balance
   ORDER BY account_no, MIN (as_on_date);
```

- First, SUM is used as analytical function to assign group number to consecutive balances less than 0.
- LAST_VALUE function is then used to find the last -ve balance in each group
- Finally, the result is aggregated based on each group. MAX(date) gives the last date, MIN(date) gives the starting date, and the difference of the two gives number of days.

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4304a/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try this and use `gone_negative` to computing specified column value for insert into another table:

```
select temp.account_no,
       temp.balance,
       temp.prev_balance,
       temp.on_date,
       temp.prev_on_date,
       case
         WHEN (temp.balance < 0 and temp.prev_balance >= 0) THEN
          1
         else
          0
       end as gone_negative
  from (select account_no,
               balance,
               on_date,
               lag(balance, 1, 0) OVER(partition by account_no ORDER BY account_no) prev_balance,
               lag(on_date, 1) OVER(partition by account_no ORDER BY account_no) prev_on_date
          from tblA
         order by account_no) temp;
```

Hope this helps pal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's on way to do it.

1. Select all records from `my_table` where the balance is positive.
2. Do a self-join and get all the records that have a `as_on_date` is greater than the current row, but the `amounts` are in negative
3. Once we get these, we cut-off the rows `WHERE` the `date difference` between the current and the previous `row` for `as_on_date` is `> 1`. We then filter the results a `outer sub query`
4. The Final `select` just groups the rows and gets the `min, max` values for the filtered rows which are grouped.

Query:

```
SELECT 
      account_no,
      min(case when row_number = 1 then balance end) as balance,
      max(mt2_date) as As_on_date,
      max(mt2_date) - mt1_date as Days_passed,
      min(mt2_date)  as Start_date
    FROM
      (
        SELECT 
         *,
         MIN(break_date) OVER( PARTITION BY mt1_date ) AS min_break_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY mt1_date ORDER BY mt2_date desc ) AS row_number
        FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
              mt1.account_no,
              mt2.balance,
              mt1.as_on_date as mt1_date,
              mt2.as_on_date as mt2_date,
              case when mt2.as_on_date - lag(mt2.as_on_date,1) over () > 1 then mt2.as_on_date end as break_date
            FROM
              my_table mt1
              JOIN my_table mt2 ON ( mt2.balance < mt1.balance AND mt2.as_on_date > mt1.as_on_date ) 
            WHERE 
              MT1.balance > 0
            order by
              mt1.as_on_date,
              mt2.as_on_date ) sub_query
        ) T
    WHERE
      min_break_date is null 
      OR mt2_date < min_break_date
    GROUP BY
      mt1_date,
      account_no
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/93c56)

I have a added a few more rows in the FIDDLE, just to test it out